# Is it possible to identify missing junit test cases by using maven?

Tags: maven

Is it possible to identify missing junit test cases by using maven? Any plugin or configuration so that we could identify that test cases are missing.

Comment: What is a `missign test case` to you?

Comment: Do you know the concept of "test coverage"?

Comment: Suppose there are no unit test cases placed in the test folder. Would it be possible to get the test coverage by using maven?

Comment: If there are no uni tests, the test coverage is zero. The test coverage measures the amount of code that is touched by the tests, it does not generate tests.